# Перебор массива через цикл в Java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть метод слияния массивов на Java:

```
public static int[] combineArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
    
    int j = 0;
    for (j = a.length; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Если передать два массива например:

```
int[] mas1 =new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] mas2 =new int[]{4,5,6};
```

То ответ будет :
1,2,3,4,5,6

Вопрос:
Скажите , после того , когда c[i] заполнится размером до 2 , что передается
в j = a.length( текущая длинна  от 0 до 2 ?) и во втором же цикле счетчик i начинается с 0 ?
можно пожалуйста вот эти моменты подробнее пояснить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, при массивах `mas1` и `mas2`, `a.length` передает 3. Причина кроется в том, что `length` - это просто размер массива. В вашем примере, второй цикл начинается с 3 индекса (4 позиции).

Comment: У меня ошибка там скорее всего во втором цикле , надо так : for(int i =a.length; i<c.length;i++).  То есть , он передает в i размер массива a. и идёт сравнение с заполненном массивом c. ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать так

```
private double[] concatArray(double[] a, double[] b) {
if (a == null)
    return b;
if (b == null)
    return a;
double[] r = new double[a.length + b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, r, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, r, a.length, b.length);
return r;
}
```

[Источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php#concat)

Comment: Да , это хороший вариант и конечно лучше подобное использовать . Но я в глубь копаю , чтобы понимать , что передается в таких случаях i =a.length -1(или без -1) это же больше на формулу похоже , а если в виде чисел

Comment: a.length это длина массива. От 1 начинается. А вот обращение к 1 элементу через 0

Answer (score 0):

Хм, а не проще

```
int[] result = Stream.concat(
Arrays.stream(a),
Arrays.stream(b))
.sort().toArray();
```

И у вас там ошибка. Замените на:

```
    for (int i = 0, j = a.length; i < b.length; i++, j++) {
        c[j] = b[i];
    }
```

Чтобы не путаться можно называть переменные чуть более очевидно :

```
int firstArrayIndex =...
```